# Авто доводка элемента управления после перетягивания.

Tags: c#, winforms

Добрый день. Есть 2 PictureBox. Мне нужно реализовать перетягивание полосатого в область серого и центрировать его в области серого. Сейчас я делаю так как на коде ниже. В двух словах, Когда мышь находится над серым квадратом то срабатывает OnDragHover и флаг устанавливаем в true, при отпускании проверяется флаг и позиция выравнивается по серому. Однако в отладчике я посмотрел, что в метод OnMouseUp я попадаю раньше чем в OnDragHover.

```
using System;
```

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms ;
using System.Drawing;

namespace Lab3 {

```
class ShapesWorker {

    private void CreateShape( Point pos = new Point() ){
       Shapes sp = new Shapes(  );
       sp.GenetateShape();
       form.Controls.Add( sp );
       sp.BringToFront( );
       sp.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler( OnMouseDown );
       sp.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler( OnMouseMove );
       sp.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler( OnMouseUp );
       sp.ChangePos( pos );
   }


   private void OnMouseDown( object sender, MouseEventArgs e ) {

       Shapes btnThis = sender as Shapes;
       btnThis.isDrop = true;
       btnThis.startPst = e.Location;
      
   }

   private void OnMouseUp( object sender, MouseEventArgs e ) {

        Shapes btnThis = sender as Shapes;
        btnThis.isDrop = false;

        
        if (  panelControl.GetMayDroped( ) ) {
            btnThis.Location = panelControl.GetPosPanel( );
        }
     
   }

   private void OnMouseMove( object sender, MouseEventArgs e ) {
        Shapes btnThis = sender as Shapes;
        if ( btnThis.isDrop == true ) {
            btnThis.Top += e.Y - btnThis.startPst.Y;
            btnThis.Left += e.X - btnThis.startPst.X;

       }
   }
}

 public class ActivePanel: Panel {
    private Panel thisPan = null;
    private bool mayDroped = false;
    
     public Point GetPosPanel( int numPanel ){
        return panelList[ numPanel ].Location;
    }

    public void SetPanel( Panel pan){
        thisPan = pan;
        thisPan.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler( OnDragHover );
        thisPan.MouseLeave += new EventHandler( OnDragLeave );

    }

    private void OnDragHover( object sender, MouseEventArgs e ) {
        mayDroped = true;
    }

    private void OnDragLeave( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
        mayDroped = false;
    }

    public bool GetMayDroped(){
        return mayDroped;
    }


 }
```

}

Как мне реализовать такое центрирование при перетягивании?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал это следующим образом:

При перетягивании ( в обработчике )  проверяю позицию в которой сейчас нахожусь и если попадаю внутрь прямоугольника,, то просто выравниваю по его координатам.

```
private void SetTargertPosition( Shapes btnThis  ) {
           Point pos = panelControl.GetPanelByColorType( btnThis.GetColor( ) );
           if ( pos.X != -1 ) {
               btnThis.ChangePos( pos );               
           }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Для перетаскивания вам нужны методы MouseMove, DragOver и DragDrop.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms742859(v=vs.110).aspx